# Checking for a specific value sequence within data during a CRC

Tags: crc, crc32

I'd like to preface this by saying that my knowledge of CRC techniques is very limited, I spent most of the day googlin' and reading things, but I can't quite find what I'm looking for. It may very well not be possible, if so just let me know!

What I have is a sequence of seemingly random data:
0xAF 0xBC 0x1F 0x5C... etc

Within this data, there is a field that is not random (that I put there), and I want to use a CRC check of the entire data set to see if this field is set to the correct value (lets say 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78). I am trying to do this sneakily and this is key because I don't want a casual observer to know that I am looking for that field - this is why I don't just read out the location I want and compare against expected value.

The field's value is constant, the rest is pretty much random. There are some fields here and there that will also be constant if that helps.

Is this possible to do? I am not limited in the number of times I do the CRC check, or which direction I go through data, or of I change the polynomial, or really anything. I can also start from the middle of the array, or the third, or whatever, but I would prefer not to start near my field of interest.

Comment: So, you're embedding the CRC inside the data you're checking, rather than outside of the boundaries of that data?  What programming languages are you using?  Have you any code for us to work with?  Because CRC calculation isn't all that difficult, programmatically, and it wouldn't be all that difficult to take two snips of data & glue them together, calculate a CRC from them, and then write that CRC between the two snips.  Unclear what you're asking, though.

Comment: No. I'm not embedding the CRC inside the data. I'm doing a CRC on the data and I want to use that operation to also check if the data I'm checking contains a specific subset of values. As you said the CRC calculation isn't difficult programmatically, so I see no sense showing you that. I don't think the language matters (it's C++). I am looking for ideas on whether it is possible to perform a CRC and have it somehow react to a subset of values.

Comment: It should be possible to add code to your CRC algorithm to check the subset of data ... it's likely going to confuse things by having a CRC check do some additional validation, but it's possible.  Do you have a code sample that you'd like help with, or are you asking something concrete?

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet, thanks for your response. I am looking for implementation/algorithm ideas, I can write the code. A bullet point list would do. I can post the CRC code in a bit, but it's just going to be like all the other CRC code out there and I'm not sure what that's going to add and I don't need help with that code in particular because it works fine. My CRC code right now just performs a CRC32 over the entire data set.

Comment: React? What do mean react?

Comment: @MarkAdler, have some predictable value.

Comment: This is not at all clear, so let me take a stab in the dark at rephrasing it to see if this is right: You want an operation that _appears_ to process all of the data, but in fact is only a function of a short string at a known location in the data. This is so that the data not at that location can take on any values, but will not affect the result of the operation. Only the data at the location of the short string should affect the result. But you don't want that location to be "obvious" in the operation being performed. Is that it?

Comment: @MarkAdler, Yes, indeed that. CRC would be ideal because I actually have to do a CRC on the data anyways, but I'm not picky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only function that comes to mind that will do what you want is a discrete wavelet transform. (A CRC will always depend on all of the bits that you are computing it over — that's kind of the point.)

You can find the coefficients to apply to the set of discrete wavelet basis functions that will give you a function with a finite basis that covers only the region of interest, using the orthogonality of the basis functions. It will appear that the wavelet functions are over the entire message, but the coefficients are rigged so that the values outside the region of interest cancel in the sum.

While this all may not be obvious to a casual reader of the code, it would be straightforward to write down the functions and coefficients, and multiply it out to see what bytes in the message are selected by the coefficients.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I will try this out and report back with how successful this was.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so, to confirm, you have something like this as your data:

```
0xAF 0xBC 0x1F 0x5C 0x11 0x1F 0x5C 0x11
0x2D 0xAB 0xBB 0xCC 0x00 0xBB 0xCC 0x00
0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 0xFF 0x56 0x78 0xFF
```

and you're trying to isolate something in a particular location of that data, e.g., to find the `0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78` value there.

To clarify, you're wanting to 1) check that value (that particular address range's value), and 2) then do a crc on the whole?  Or are you wanting to integrate the hunt for the value into the crc algorithm?

- Honestly trying to understand where you're going.  I realize this isn't really an answer, but it's a better place for this than in a comment.

Comment: I want to integrate the hunt for the value into the CRC. It doesn't really have to be a full on CRC. In fact it could probably be a CRC and something else along side that isn't just " if x == 012 ". Thanks!